# questions about excluded values in rational expressions

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Two examples, one from my algebra textbook and another from Wolfram that create this question.
I fully realize that zero cannot exist in the denominator, but the book seems to distinguish between removable discontinuities and values of a variable that would cause a zero to exist in the denominator.   My enclosures both show these examples.[image]

Wolfram is as follows:

$(1/x)(x/(x+1)).

The problem shows the x values being canceled and then shows that $x$ cannot $=0$.  But the final answer of $1/(x+1)$ does not exist for $x=-1$, yet this exclusion is not listed.

My text shows the exact same problem and says excluded values of $x$ are $x$ cannot $=0$ not $x$ cannot $=-1$.

Can someone help me understand this dilemma?

Comment: Think about this: if I plug in $0$ for $x$ in $\frac1x\cdot\frac x{x+1}$, what do I get? I don't get $1$, I get an indeterminate value. Hence, the expression is not defined for $x=0$.

Comment: Similar to Don Thousand's comment:  The algebraic manipulation of $\frac{1}{x} \times \frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{1}{x+1}$ is **only valid** when $x \neq 0.$  This is because the assertion $\frac{x}{x} = 1$ is **only valid** when $x \neq 0.$

Comment: I do not think you understand his question, he is asking why $x=-1$ isn't listed as an excluded value for $\frac{1}{x+1}$ even though that value makes the expression undefined.

Comment: @SomeGuy +1: good point.  Assuming that your interpretation of the OP's query is accurate, my only explanation is that $x = -1$ should be excluded, and that whatever analysis (computer software driven or paper-pencil drive) that failed to exclude it is in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The textbook answer to the question is not stating the domain, but stating under what circumstances the simplification is valid.  The step

$$\frac{1}{x}\cdot\frac{x}{x+1} = \frac{1}{x+1}$$

is valid only when $x\neq 0$.  The two expressions are equal otherwise.

Comment: Ah, this now makes sense.  In wolfram, they state x cannot =0, but further in the analysis they state the domain is x not 0 AND x not -1.  I see this now.